# Make sum of int array change with changes in array elements

Tags: arrays, pointers, julia

I have an collection of arrays of the following way:

```
arr = Array{Array{Int64,1},1}( [ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6] , [7,8,9] ] )
```

I want to define a new aray `sum` such that `sums[i] = sum(arr[i])`
but in a dynamic way such that if I change an element of `arr[i]`, `sums[i]` changes automatically. For example:

```
julia> sums
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  6
 15
 24

julia> arr[1][1] = 3
3

julia> sums
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  8
 15
 24
```

Is this possible to do? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MappedArrays`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/MappedArrays.jl). `MappedArrays` provide a "view" `M` of an array `A` so that `M[i] = f(A[i])`. All you need to do add `MappedArrays` package by `]add MappedArrays` and start using it with `sum` function. Note that the transformation is lazy, meaning that it will compute the values in `M` when you try to access them. Therefore, after an update to `A`, you will see the change in `M` when you access entries of `M`.

```
julia> using MappedArrays

julia> arr = [ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6] , [7,8,9] ] 
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]
 [7, 8, 9]

julia> M = mappedarray(sum, arr)
3-element mappedarray(sum, ::Array{Array{Int64,1},1}) with eltype Int64:
  6
 15
 24

julia> arr[1][2] = 10
10

julia> M
3-element mappedarray(sum, ::Array{Array{Int64,1},1}) with eltype Int64:
 14
 15
 24
```

Comment: It seems to work, but the package seems a little old and not currently manteined. I thought there could be an easier solution in the new (after 1.0) versions of Julia.

Comment: @AldoSayeg It is a very lightweight package around 200 lines implemented in pure Julia, and it should just work. It does not require frequent updates maybe just a few tweaks. The last commit which does not really change anything from the end-user perspective is just two months old which IMO is pretty recent for such a package. You can write your own mapped array using Julia's array interface. I do not think, though, it will be as simple as using a package who already does that.
Here is the code: https://github.com/JuliaArrays/MappedArrays.jl/blob/master/src/MappedArrays.jl

Comment: I think the pacage is good enough, after reviewing it. Thanks a lot